# Automapper performance issue only when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, automapper, visual-studio-2015

In my WPF application I am using AutoMapper to map from the entities to the domain objects.

For one particular mapping I am seeing a substantial slow down when running the application with debugging (F5) versus without (CTRL + F5). 
Without debugging this mapping takes < 1 second, but with debugging it takes ~14 seconds.

The domain objects (simplified for brevity):

```
public class CompanyModel : UpdateableModel
{
    public CompanyModel() : this(true){}

    public CompanyModel(bool isNewModel) : base(isNewModel)
    {
        Projects = new ObservableCollectionEx<ProjectModel>();
        Projects.ItemPropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
    }

    public int? Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyXref { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollectionEx<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set;}
}

public class ProjectModel : UpdateableModel
{
    public ProjectModel() : this(true){}

    public ProjectModel(bool isNewModel) : base(isNewModel)
    {
        Tasks = new ObservableCollectionEx<ProjectTaskModel>();

        SetPropertyDefault(() => StartDate, DateTime.Today);
        SetPropertyDefault(() => EndDate, DateTime.Today);

        // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
        Tasks.ItemPropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("Tasks");
    }

    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string BillingCurrency { get; set; }
    public string ExternalXref { get; set; }
    public bool IsChargeable { get; set; }        
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int TimeTypeId { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollectionEx<ProjectTaskModel> Tasks { get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTaskModel : UpdateableModel
{
    public ProjectTaskModel() : this(true){}

    public ProjectTaskModel(bool isNewModel) : base(isNewModel)
    {
        SetPropertyDefault(() => StartDate, DateTime.Today);
        SetPropertyDefault(() => EndDate, DateTime.Today);
    }

    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }        
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ExternalXref { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

The entities:

```
public class CompanyEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyXref { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProjectEntity> Projects { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExternalXref { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsChargeable { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual int TimeTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyEntity ClientCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ProjectTaskEntity> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTaskEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string ProjectTaskName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExternalXref { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual ProjectEntity Project { get; set; }
}
```

Finally the mappings, all properties are currently explicitly mapped:

```
CreateMap<CompanyEntity, CompanyModel>()
    .ConstructUsing((CompanyEntity src) => new CompanyModel(false))
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Name, src => src.CompanyName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.CompanyXref, src => src.CompanyXref)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.IsActive, src => src.IsActive)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Projects, src => src.Projects)
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.State);

CreateMap<ProjectEntity, ProjectModel>()
    .ConstructUsing((ProjectEntity src) => new ProjectModel(false))
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Name, src => src.ProjectName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Description, src => src.Description)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.BillingCurrency, src => src.CurrencyId)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.StartDate, src => src.StartDate)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.EndDate, src => src.EndDate)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.ExternalXref, src => src.ExternalXref)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.IsActive, src => src.IsActive)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.IsChargeable, src => src.IsChargeable)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Tasks, src => src.Tasks)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.TimeTypeId, src => src.TimeTypeId)
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.State);

CreateMap<ProjectTaskEntity, ProjectTaskModel>()
    .ConstructUsing((ProjectTaskEntity src) => new ProjectTaskModel(false))
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Name, src => src.ProjectTaskName)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.Description, src => src.Description)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.StartDate, src => src.StartDate)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.EndDate, src => src.EndDate)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.ExternalXref, src => src.ExternalXref)
    .MapMember(dest => dest.IsActive, src => src.IsActive)
    .IgnoreMember(dest => dest.State);
```

When the mapping is performed there are 16 companies, 122 total projects, and each project only has one task currently.

I did try ignoring various properties on the mappings and it seems to be the Tasks collection at the project level that is causing this; with it ignored the mapping takes 2 seconds instead of 14.

Is there something about how Visual Studio hosts the application for debugging that could cause this performance issue?

Comment: I am starting to think this problem may not be an interaction between AutoMapper and the debugger, but rather with NHibernate and the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly download an alternate CSharp IDE run it in debugging mode there and see if there is a difference.
SharpDev is an opensource IDE that is very nice and supports C# projects.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/

It would at least be interesting and a simple way to try an alternative.
SharpDev also has a code profiler built-in which may indicate what the issue is.

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately my application is using 4.6 so this isn't an option. Also as to your profiling comment, visual studio 2015 has the same capability, but i have not been able to glean any information from it.

Comment: @Phaeze That's unfortunate SharpDev doesn't support 4.6 yet. I just created a SharpDev project and added all your classes and the nuget ObservableCollectionEx.  I can build project except i need BaseEntity and Updateable Model.  Would you like to post those and I"ll try building and see what I get?

Comment: Base Entity only contains an int Id property and I've posted the updateable model code here https://github.com/MadillJ/InterstingCodeCollection/blob/master/UpdateableModel.cs it does use some c# 6 functionality

Comment: Okay, I will try it. The C# 6 functionality may constrain me from getting it to build, but I will try.